# What were the broad meanings of the various (nominal) declination classes in proto-IE?

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, lexical-semantics

As everyone (who is familiar with proto-Indo-European) knows, it is an inflectional language with several cases, a few accent-ablaut patterns, and a number of (thematic/athematic) declination classes. For example, *mother*, *father*, *water* were r-stem nouns; *work*, *nest*, *wolf* were o-stem; *gift* was i-stem; *son* was u-stem; etc.

Most of these types come with a special deverbative suffix, which bears a specific meaning - e.g. the r-stem indicated an actor/doer; the i-stem appeared mainly in nouns, formed from a verb root with the suffix *-ti-*, which had denoted an act, state, object, or tool; etc.

My question is if the other declination types had some general (broad) meaning, like the two given examples, or they didn't specify anything besides that the word is a noun? In particular, was there any semantic difference between the o-stem and e-stem nouns or they were just "allophones" of each other?

PS If I've used somewhere wrong terminology, please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2):

The ***-ios/-i̯os*** nouns/adjectives usually meant the origin or belonging of the thing, for instance, ***nea̯ui̯os*** "of a ship", ***smğelbhi̯os*** "of the same womb, uterine", ***su̯oini̯os*** "wife's sister's husband" (from ***su̯oinia̯*** "wife's sister"), ***su̯esri̯os*** "sister's son". This possibly developed from Locative case whose ending was ***-i***. Thus, ***su̯esri*** would mean "at the sister", ***nea̯ui*** would mean "on a/the ship". Also used as comparative as in ***seni̯os*** "older".

The ***-ter*** nouns meant agents. Those whose job, work, or design was to do some function. Thus, ***censter*** meant "speaker", ***doma̯ter*** meant "tamer", ***peq̆ter*** meant "cook". This suffix also was used for the terms for relatives.

The ***-tor*** suffix also created the agent noun but it meant somebody who did the action irrespective of whether it was his usual occupation. Thus, if ***peq̆ter*** meant "cook", ***peq̆tor*** would mean the one who cooked (a thing).

The ***-teros*** suffix meant roughly the same as -ward suffix in English or comparative. The one of a pair who has the quality manifested the most. Such as in ***decsteros*** "the one more to the right", ***u̯eiteros*** "the more far one", ***e̯enteros*** "the inner one".

The ***-istos*** suffix meant superlative. Thus, ***ğra̯uistos*** meant "heaviest", ***dlonghistos*** meant "longest", ***a̯ristos*** meant "of the best sort".

Another superlative suffix was ***-mmos/-immos/-ismmos/-tmmos*** as in ***e̯eĝhstmmos*** "outermost"

The ***-trom, -dhrom, -tlom, -dhlom*** suffixes meant instruments and tools. Thus ***a̯ero̯trom*** "plow", ***seddhlom*** "saddle", ***see̯tlom*** "sieve" etc.

The ***-ia̯/-a̯*** suffixes meant collective number, abstract things and feminine gender. Thus ***preu̯ia̯*** "mistress", ***neptia̯*** "female nephew".

The ***-r/-n*** alternating stems belonged to the very ancient nouns, such as ***u̯odr*** "water" (gen. ***u̯edns***, adj ***u̯odnos***), ***u̯esr*** "spring" etc.

The ***-mn*** suffix meant neuter(non-animate) nouns, having certain properties. Such as ***a̯eĝmn*** "train", ***e̯neo̯mn*** "name", ***ĝneo̯mn*** "sign", ***see̯mn*** "seed".

The ***-kos*** suffix indicated material composition or origin. Such as in ***leukos*** "bright", ***a̯i̯uenkos*** "young".

The ***-ikos*** suffix meant "having to do with..."

The ***-iskos*** suffix indicated affiliation or place of origin.

The ***-ros*** was the default adjectival suffix as in ***a̯rĝros*** "shining"

The ***-tos*** suffix formed possessive adjectives (having X).

The ***-mos*** suffix produced action and event nouns such as in ***ğhermos*** "warmth, heat", ***sreumos*** "stream".

The ***-los*** was used for creating deminutives.

The ***-u̯ents*** suffix meant "rich in".

There were other suffixes as well.